# Miracast projecting software (not drivers) for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I am looking into possibilities to project my Windows 10 laptop desktop over Miracast.

My laptop has Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 card; typically it is said:

https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/intel-hd-3000-miracast-on-win-10-issue/td-p/624087

> HD 3000 graphics are not supported on Windows 10

Also, `dxdiag` days: "Miracast: Not Supported by Graphics driver"; and in Administrative `cmd.exe`, running `NETSH WLAN SHOW DRIVER` says:

> Wireless Display Supported: No (Graphics Driver: No, Wi-Fi Driver: Yes)

So apparently, in Windows 10, Miracast support depends on device driver capabilities.

However, looking at https://askubuntu.com/questions/318298/ubuntu-as-miracast-sender-receiver I can see that there are (what seem to be) *user-space* software (that is, non-driver) Miracast solutions for Ubuntu:

- https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast
- https://blogs.gnome.org/benzea/2019/01/30/gnome-screencast/

So, I was wondering - is there something similar for Windows 10? Either a user-space application, or some sort of a virtual display driver?

BTW, I looked into VLC, and it seems to have a Chromecast capability ( e.g. https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/stream-videos-vlc-chromecast/ ), but not Miracast ( [Streaming to Miracast Wifi Display Dongle Receiver - The VideoLAN Forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=125342) ); similarly, I am aware there are Chromecast addons for Chrome browser, but I haven't been able to find something similar for Miracast.

Answer (score 0):

[Reflector](https://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector) may work for what you need, it does stream to miracast.